# How to call function of functions.php in url using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in word press, i want to hit function inside "functions.php" in my website url,how can i do this ? Here is my function in "functions.php", i want to use this function like "http://myurl.com/folder_contents"

```
function folder_contents() {
echo "Hello world";
// your code here
die(); 
}
```

Comment: Does this answers your question? [Calling a function from functions.php in custom page/ blog post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341965/calling-a-function-from-functions-php-in-custom-page-blog-post)

Comment: @Justinas: No, because i dont want to use any "template" , can i use function ( in functions.php file) directly in browser/url  ?

Comment: No, because that's not how PHP and server requests in general works - someone must listen for page in URL, either it's dynamic routing or actual file

Comment: No, you can not. Imaging what a massive security problem that would be, if I could invoke just any arbitrary function you might have in your code, from the outside, by creating a specific URL ...

Comment: You should set up a proper _endpoint_ for this, using the Rest API. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Answer (score 1):

A function can't directly be called in the URL. You need to bind the function with an endpoint to make it work. The Process is described briefly in [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

In Short, here is the process of registering a custom endpoint:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'mycustomRoute/', 'content/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'customFunction',
  ) );
} );
```

Function to display the content:

```
function customFunction() {
    echo "I am coming from a custom Endpoint";
}
```

On hitting the endpoint(wp-json/mycustomRoute/content/), The Data will be displayed. More details are included in the article mentioned above.